# How to check if elements of a multiplication table are all associative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, associative-array, finite-group-theory

I want to check if a multiplication table like 
the following is not a code but I could not find a way to write it another way

```
*  0 1 2
0 |0 1 0
1 |0 0 0 
2 |0 1 1
```

It is store as a list with sublists in my code like

```
[[0,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,1,1]]

#How to write a function which checks elements satisfy the condition x*(y*z) = (x*y)*z ? 

#This is what I have so far: 

def is_associative(X):
    n = len(X)
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        a.append[i]
        for j in range(n):
            a[j]*a[j] = X[j]
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, isn't `x*(y*z)` always equal to  `(x*y)*z`? Unless `*` is not a multiplication in your case?

Comment: @cglacet Based on the table, `1 * 0 == 0`, but `0 * 1 == 1`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand the table either, if what you are interpreting is correct then `*` is indeed not a multiplication but something else (an arbitrary function I guess?).

Comment: That is too hard, you need to do it in smaller steps. (1) Write a function that takes `x`, `y`, `z` and returns `x*(y*z)`. (2) Write another function that returns `(x*y)*z`. (3) Write yet another function that computes both products by calling the previous functions, compares the values and returns whether they are equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop over all three variables:

```
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        for z in range(n):
```

And then you need to check if

```
X[X[x, y], z] == X[x, X[y, z]]
```

for all values.